# Tridion New UI Preview Site is not reflecting with the changes unless pulished

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I have new UI setup and noticing that when ever I update a page it is not refreshing with the updated changes. I do not see either the page_{sessionId/GUID}.aspx created either.

Checked the session preview DB and I see the changes in PAGE_CONTENT table with new rendered content, so seems like session preview is working fine but the Preview site is not able to get the changes and refresh the UI.

I have checked all the preview handlers and mappings for .aspx and made sure they are correct in web.config. Any thoughts on why the preview site not showing up the changes?

I have the session preview DB setup in cd_storage_conf.xml.

```xml
<StorageBindings>
  <Bundle src="preview_dao_bundle.xml"/>
</StorageBindings>
<Wrappers>
  <Wrapper Name="SessionWrapper">
    <Timeout>120000</Timeout>
    <Storage Type="persistence" Id="db-session-webservice" dialect="MSSQL"
             Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
      <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" 
            IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
      <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost" />
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_SessionPreview" />
        <Property Name="user" Value="usr" />
        <Property Name="password" Value="pwd" />
      </DataSource>
    </Storage>
  </Wrapper>
</Wrappers>
```

web.config (handlers):

```xml
<add verb="GET" path="*.htm" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
<add verb="GET" path="*.jpg" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
<add verb="GET" path="*.png" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
<add verb="GET" path="*.html" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
<add name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule" />
```

Log (timestamp and DEBUG prefix removed):

```
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:id, value=tridion_db59279b-7d37-4b2e-ad98-eaaa6af7038e
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:id, value=tridion_db59279b-7d37-4b2e-ad98-eaaa6af7038e
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:tracking:id, value=tridion_d1fa1017-a28d-4f48-a790-b74f78c69314
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:tracking:id, value=tridion_d1fa1017-a28d-4f48-a790-b74f78c69314
SearchClaimProcessor - No match found for referrer string http://uidemo.practice.com/en/Product/musk.aspx
SearchClaimProcessor - No match found for referrer string http://uidemo.practice.com/en/Product/musk.aspx
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:devicetype, value=Desktop
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:devicetype, value=Desktop
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:mobiledevice, value=NotMobile
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:acceptlanguage, value=en-US
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:mobiledevice, value=NotMobile
ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:acceptlanguage, value=en-US
PageHandler - The session wrappers are correctly installed.
```

Any thoughts/pointers on what might be going wrong...?
(sorry for the long post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION/FIX**

Applying the new hotifx "CD_2011.1.1.81686" on preview application resolved the problem. Hotifx could be downloaded from https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx (login required)

Answer (score 4):

After the "The session wrappers are correctly installed." message, once I make a change I get a LOT of feedback on my logs (in debug). This is the short version...

```
DEBUG PageHandler - The session wrappers are correctly installed.
DEBUG SessionManagerImpl - Retrieved the session on the current execution thread: PreviewSession [sessionId=db5c1e84-649f-4635-bbdd-fb6683e98b07, expirationDate=2012-06-29 12:31:24.65].
DEBUG PageHandler - The session db5c1e84-649f-4635-bbdd-fb6683e98b07 was found loaded!
DEBUG DynamicMetaRetriever - Searching for pageMeta for url='http://localhost:81/'.
DEBUG MetaResolverFactory - Fetching meta resolver for PAGE_META meta data type.
DEBUG MetaResolverFactory - Fetching meta resolver for PAGE_META meta data type.
DEBUG MappingsResolverImpl - Getting publication mapping for http://localhost:81/
DEBUG MappingsStrategyContext - Resolving url using strategy com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.mappingsstrategy.impl.StaticMappingsStrategy
DEBUG StaticMappingsStrategy - Resolving: http://localhost:81/
DEBUG ProtocolOptionMatcher - Mapped Protocol match with the url. Protocol is [http].
DEBUG ProtocolOptionMatcher - The calculated weight is [1].
DEBUG DomainOptionMatcher - The Domain extracted from the url is: [localhost]
DEBUG DomainOptionMatcher - The mapped Domain is: [localhost]
DEBUG DomainOptionMatcher - Mapped Domain match with the url. Mapped Domain is [localhost] and extracted Domain is [localhost].
DEBUG DomainOptionMatcher - The calculated weight is [10000].
DEBUG PortOptionMatcher - The Port extracted from the url is: [:81]
DEBUG PortOptionMatcher - The mapped Port is: [81]
```

[...]

```
DEBUG JPAPreviewSessionDAO - Retrieving PreviewSession by sessionId: db5c1e84-649f-4635-bbdd-fb6683e98b07
```

[...]

```
SessionManagerImpl - Retrieved the session on the current execution thread: PreviewSession [sessionId=db5c1e84-649f-4635-bbdd-fb6683e98b07, expirationDate=Fri Jun 29 12:31:25 EDT 2012].
```

And it then loads with the correct updates.

I don't see anything wrong with the config you posted, so here's my config for the cd_ambient_conf.xml;

```xml
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="6.1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd">
  <Cartridges>
    <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
    <Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
  </Cartridges>
  <ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>
</Configuration>
```

and cd_dynamic_conf:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="6.1"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_dynamic_conf.xsd">
    <URLMappings>
        <StaticMappings>
            <Publications>
                <Publication Id="5">
                    <Host Domain="localhost" Port="81" Protocol="http" Path=""/>
                </Publication>
            </Publications>
        </StaticMappings>
        <StorageMapping IdentifyPublicationByProperty="publicationUrl"/>
    </URLMappings>
    <TCDLEngine>
        <Renderer Class="com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLRenderer">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="prop1" Value="value1"/>
                <Property Name="prop2" Value="value2"/>
            </Properties>
        </Renderer>
    </TCDLEngine>
</Configuration>
```

Hopefully this helps.

N

Comment: Thanks Nuno. I am double checking the configurations and the log entries as well..

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, still not sure of the solution yet. I have web site in 2 languages one with /en and one with /fr under the same IIS directory. For some reason either UI is not able to understand or not working properly with virtual directory /en and /fr. I even added <Host Domain="localhost" Port="81" Protocol="http" Path="/en"/>, but no luck. I tried the same config with no virtual directories and UI working fine..

Comment: Interesting. That should work - can you try with the same configuration (with the Path setting) on cd_link_conf?

Comment: I have changed the ROOT structure group directory to /en or /es. Link config does not have any path setting and I assumed the same for cd_dynamic_conf.xml as well. Since it is not working, so I tried adding path to dynamic conf. Now I tried with same for link_conf , now the link resolving is showing up multiple /en (expected anyway).. UI still does not update.. I am enabling some trace for failed requests on IIS to see if I can get anything..

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to work through the some parts of it, basically I removed the /en from cd_dynamic_conf.xml on both webapp and service. Now I see that the page I am editing creating the temp page with guid etc.., but the preview throws an error like unable to find the file artdetails.aspx even though artdetail.aspx and artdetails_GUID.aspx both exist on docroot.. somehow UI is confused when you have virtual directory. I will open a support ticket for this.. FYI.. If I remove the virtual directory and keep everything at the root all is working well..

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file cd_ambient_conf.xml; UNcomment the follwoing line

```
<Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
```

and then try to edit you will be able to preview the changes

Thanks & regards
Abhijit Angre