# Tridion UI - Preview Not Updating

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

Today I have installed Tridion UI according to the documentation on http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/.  All seems to be working with the exception of "Update Preview" function.  After making a change to a component the page correctly shows that the preview is out of date but clicking the "Update Preview" button reloads the page with no error other than the same warning being displayed "The preview for this page is not up to date".

I see there is another post related to this ([Tridion New UI Preview Site is not reflecting with the changes unless pulished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263963/tridion-new-ui-preview-site-is-not-reflecting-with-the-changes-unless-pulished)) but I am not using any virtual directories.

I have worked my way through warnings and errors I discovered in the logs to be left with only one warning (both on the deployer and staging site):

> 2012-07-05 19:44:25,085 WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised

with debug logging enabled I see AmbientDataContext just defaults to com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext which I assume is correct?

Occasionally, a session cleanup error will be displayed - not sure if this is related to the problem though:

`$
2012-07-05 19:52:55,300 ERROR SessionManagerImpl - Could not clean session storage after session expired!
com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Exception while cleaning-up session data: Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionWrapperFactory.cleanupSessionData(SessionWrapperFactory.java:154) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.expireSession(SessionManagerImpl.java:415) [cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.performCleanup(SessionManagerImpl.java:231) [cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionsCleanerMonitor.run(SessionsCleanerMonitor.java:54) [cd_session.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
2012-07-05 19:52:55,300 ERROR SessionsCleanerMonitor - Could not perform sessions clean-up. Will retry in 120000 milliseconds.
com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionHandlingException: Could not clean session storage after session expired: Exception while cleaning-up session data: Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Exception while cleaning-up session data: Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Exception while cleaning-up session data: Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity, Rollback took place, didn't removed., attempt to create delete event with null entity, attempt to create delete event with null entity
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.expireSession(SessionManagerImpl.java:444) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.performCleanup(SessionManagerImpl.java:231) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionsCleanerMonitor.run(SessionsCleanerMonitor.java:54) ~[cd_session.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated?  Not sure what else to try.

Thanks

Phil

Comment: The error message indicates quite clearly that you don't have Ambient Data Framework installed correctly - apparently neither on the staging nor on the cd_upload site.

Comment: Check web.config (.NET) or web.xml (Java) to ensure Ambient Framework filters are correctly configured. After that, double check the cd_ambient_conf.xml - Also, did you notice that there is a sample webapp shipped with the UI installers? You can use that to compare to your configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue turned out to be incorrect "Publication Path" and "Publication URL" values within the publication properties.  After reverting back to default values it now works - big thanks to Tridion PS for this.

Answer (score 6):

That error happens because the temporal files that UI creates everytime there is a change on a page or content  or the "Update Preview" button is pressed are not created so when it tries to delete them will show you that error. So, this error is more a sympton that something else is wrong rather than an error itself. What you would need to check is wether those temp files have been created or not.

Answer (score 3):

This section of the documentation (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_89D69D4B67C340388652DEAECA6B5B79) walks through setting up the session preview.

It looks like you've missed some steps for configuring this part.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses - I tried Nuno's tip of comparing against the shipped sample apps for the deployer and staging site and even set up a new deployer and staging site from these examples and only changed the bare minimum of settings.  Still the same issue though with the same AmbientDataContext warning in the log.  The session preview database is being updated so it looks like it is partly working at least.  Can anyone tell me whether I should be trying to fix the AmbientDataContext warning or whether this warning also appears in the logs in a working setup?

Comment: As Emma suggests, the problem probably occurs while deploying. Your Session Preview database is being updated correctly, but do the (ASPX/JSP) files also end up on disk of the web server once you request them?